# OnClickListener not functioning as expected

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, buttonclick

I have an onclicklistener at the line:

```
mAssistUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_instr_btn);
        mAssistUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

which is supposed to call:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == mAssistUpdateButton) {
```

but it does not seem to reach that point in the code. I've looked it over several times and cannot seem to figure out what I've done wrong.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

SOURCE:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ConfigFinalActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "ConfigActivity";
    TelephonyManager tm;
    AlertDialog mErrorAlert = null;
    private Notification mNotification = null;
    private Button mXButton = null;
    private Button mAssistUpdateButton = null;
    private Button mAssistInstrButton = null;
    private Button mReadAgainButton = null;
    private int mInstructionNumber = 0;
    public static ArrayList<String> NameArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> ValueArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> nameArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> ApnArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mmscArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mmsportArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mmsproxyArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> portArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> proxyArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static int count;
    public static int TotalSteps = 8;
    int i, g = 0, result = 0;
    String Result = "";
    public static ContentValues Values = new ContentValues();
    XmlParserHandlerFinal handler;

    public static final Uri APN_TABLE_URI = Uri
            .parse("content://telephony/carriers");
    public static String Base_URL = "https://www.mysettings.com/";
    public static InputStream stream = null;
    UpdateActivity update;
    public static String status;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int version = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        update = new UpdateActivity();
        nameArr = update.getnameArr();
        ApnArr = update.getApnArr();
        mmscArr = update.getMMSCArr();
        mmsproxyArr = update.getMmscProxyArr();
        mmsportArr = update.getMmsPortArr();
        proxyArr = update.getMmscProxyArr();
        portArr = update.getMmsPortArr();
        count = update.getCount();
        if (ApnArr.isEmpty() || mmscArr.isEmpty() || mmsportArr.isEmpty()
                || mmsproxyArr.isEmpty() || proxyArr.isEmpty()
                || portArr.isEmpty()) {
            tryagain();
        } else if (version < VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {

            // Update APN table
            try {
                result = updateTable();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }// Settings updated with this atomic call
            catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (result != -1) {
                status = "success";

            } else {
                status = "failure";
            }

            if (status.equals("success")) {
                completeUpdate();
            } else if (status.equals("failure")) {
                tryagain();
                // showAlert(getString(R.string.unchanged_net10_dialog));
            }

        } else {// ICS and later versions

            // Reduce number of steps to 6
            TotalSteps = 6;
            setContentView(R.layout.assist_instructions);
    //      String assistUpdate = getString(R.string.instructions_1);
    //      CharSequence styledText = Html.fromHtml(assistUpdate);
            TextView assistText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.apn_app_text_cta2);
    //      assistText.setText(styledText);
            mAssistUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_instr_btn);
            mAssistUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        }
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == mAssistUpdateButton) {

            // Update button for ICS and up is selected
            // Get the TextView in the Assist Update UI

            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.apn_app_text_cta2);
            String text = "";
            CharSequence styledText = text;
            switch (mInstructionNumber) {

            case 0:

                // Retrieve the instruction string resource corresponding the
                // 2nd set of instructions
        //      text = String.format(getString(R.string.instructions_3),
    //                  TotalSteps);
//      styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
                // Update the TextView with the correct set of instructions
                //tv.setText(styledText);
                // Increment instruction number so the correct instructions
                // string resource can be retrieve the next time the update
                // button is pressed
                mInstructionNumber++;
                break;

            case 1:
                // First set of instructions for step by step process to update
                // the APN Settings to the corresponding layout
                //setContentView(R.layout.screen5);
////                String one_text = String.format(getString(R.string.one),
////                        TotalSteps);
////                CharSequence styledText_one = Html.fromHtml(one_text);
//              TextView one = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_one);
//              one.setTextSize(18);
//              one.setText(styledText_one);
//              String two_text = String.format(getString(R.string.two),
//                      TotalSteps);
//              CharSequence styledText_two = Html.fromHtml(two_text);
//              TextView two = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_two);
//              two.setTextSize(18);
//              two.setText(styledText_two);
//              String three_text = String.format(getString(R.string.three),
//                      TotalSteps);
//              CharSequence styledText_three = Html.fromHtml(three_text);
//              TextView three = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_three);
        //      three.setTextSize(18);
            //  three.setText(styledText_three);
                mAssistUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_instr_btn);
                mAssistUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(this);
                mInstructionNumber++;
                break;

            case 2:
                // second set of instructions for step by step process to update
                // the APN Settings to the corresponding layout
            //  setContentView(R.layout.screen6);
            //  String four_text = String.format(getString(R.string.four),
        //              TotalSteps);
        //      styledText = Html.fromHtml(four_text);
        //      TextView four = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_four);
        //      four.setTextSize(18);
        //      four.setText(styledText);
        //      String five_text = String.format(getString(R.string.five),
            //          TotalSteps);
            //  styledText = Html.fromHtml(five_text);
            //  TextView five = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_five);
            //  five.setTextSize(18);
            //  five.setText(styledText);
        //      String six_text = String.format(getString(R.string.six),
//                      TotalSteps);
//              styledText = Html.fromHtml(six_text);
//              TextView six = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_six);
//              six.setTextSize(18);
//              six.setText(styledText);
//          //  String seven_text = String.format(getString(R.string.seven),
                //      TotalSteps);
            //  styledText = Html.fromHtml(seven_text);
            //  TextView seven = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_seven);
        //      seven.setTextSize(18);
        //      seven.setText(styledText);
            //  String eight_text = String.format(getString(R.string.eight),
                //      TotalSteps);
            //  styledText = Html.fromHtml(eight_text);
            //  TextView eight = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_eight);
        //      eight.setTextSize(18);
        //      eight.setText(styledText);

                // just for testing
                Result = "success";
                mAssistUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_instr_btn);
                if (Result.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                    mAssistUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(this);
                } else if (Result.equalsIgnoreCase("failure")) {
                    // // Displaying final layout after failure of Post-ICS
                    // settings
                    // read the result in the response ..if success go ahead
                    // else load the tryagain screen

        //          setContentView(R.layout.tryagain);
        //          setContentView(R.layout.tryagain);
                    String tryAgainText = "";
                    CharSequence styledTryAgainText;

//                  tryAgainText = String.format(
//                          getString(R.string.tryagain_text1), TotalSteps);
//                  styledTryAgainText = Html.fromHtml(tryAgainText);
//                  TextView tryAgain1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tryagain_text1);
//                  tryAgain1.setText(styledTryAgainText);

//                  tryAgainText = String.format(
//                          getString(R.string.tryagain_text2), TotalSteps);
//                  styledTryAgainText = Html.fromHtml(tryAgainText);
//                  TextView tryAgain2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tryagain_text2);
//                  tryAgain2.setText(styledTryAgainText);
//
//                  tryAgainText = String.format(
//                          getString(R.string.tryagain_text3), TotalSteps);
//                  styledTryAgainText = Html.fromHtml(tryAgainText);
//                  TextView tryAgain3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tryagain_text3);
//                  tryAgain3.setText(styledTryAgainText);

                }

                mInstructionNumber++;
                break;
            case 3:
                // final set of instructions

            //  setContentView(R.layout.assist_instructions_update);
            //  String last_instr_text = String.format(
        //              getString(R.string.instructions_5), TotalSteps);
            //  styledText = Html.fromHtml(last_instr_text);
            //  TextView last_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.apn_app_text_cta3);
            //  last_text.setText(styledText);

//      //      String last_instr_text1 = String.format(
//                      getString(R.string.thatsit), TotalSteps);
//              styledText = Html.fromHtml(last_instr_text1);
//              TextView last_text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.thatsIt);
//              last_text1.setText(styledText);

                String mreadAgaintext = String
                        .format(getString(R.string.read_again_text));
                styledText = Html.fromHtml(mreadAgaintext);

                mAssistInstrButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_instr_btn);
            //ReadAgainButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.read_again_btn);

            //ReadAgainButton.setText(styledText);
                mAssistInstrButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        //mReadAgainButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
        } else if (v == mAssistInstrButton) {
            // "LET'S DO THIS" Button in final instructions screen for ICS and
            // up is selected
            Values = getValues();
            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS));
            try {
                showNotification();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finish();
```

Comment: Use a debugger. We aren't going to read 1000 lines of code for you.

Comment: Have you tried replacing v==mAssistsUpdateButton with v.getId()==R.id.assist_instr_btn?

Comment: Also which import did you use for onclicklistener, the view?

Comment: does it not reach the onClick at all or is your "v =="-check not working?

Comment: @danijoo - I just tried replacing it per your suggestion - still nothing happens when I click assist_instr_btn

Comment: @Nick - import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

Comment: just a little side note... you can use /* commented */ to comment out large blocks of code and it looks a little nicer than ////////, not to mention it is faster.

Comment: @ bofredo - it reaches the line  mAssistUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(this); but then the debugger opens a new window that states "Activity.class (in the tab where it normally shows the class name) then Class File Editor: Source Not Found similar to this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/SCyBR.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compare views objects like that.  Typically you compare button id's like so:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.assist_instr_btn:
    case R.id.button2:
    }
}
```

edit: I also suggest you read into testing object equality in Java.  Using `==` is fine for primitives, but not usually for objects.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the right import? It should be

```
import android.view.View.OnclickListener
```

Answer (score 0):

like trevor-e said, it's preferred to compare ids

```
public void onClick(View v) {    
    switch(v.getId()) {   
      case R.id.btn_1:   
      ...    
      break;   
    case R.id.btn_2:   
      ...   
      break;   
    }   
}
```

if you want to compare objects (views in your case, you should use ".equals". your method will be like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {    
    if(v.equals(mAssistsUpdateButton )) {   
      //your code
    }else if (v.equals(mButton2 )) {   
      //your code
    }
}
```

the above is correct but I think that comparing ids is faster

Hope this helps
Cheers